# Woocommerce - Hook functions.php to show products

Tags: variables, filter, woocommerce, archive

I need to show products based on passed variable.
Example...

If I pass:
index.php?post_type=product&product_cat=shoes&myfilter=typeA

I want that the archive product page shows me all shoes with size 52, 53 and 54 if variable myfilter contains "typeA".

How can I do that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about you go look for a plugin that can do that? Googling f.e. “Woocommerce filter products” brings up https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-products-filter/, would looks promising.

Comment: Nope, I need to do that with hook. Can you help me?

Comment: Well then you probably want to hook into an action such as `pre_get_posts`, check if it is the right archive query, and then modify the query object according to your filtering needs.

Comment: Yep, but problem is that I don't know how to do this. Can you provide me an example?

Comment: The WP Codes page on the mentioned action has basic examples. And the page on `WP_Query` has more examples how to make the query filter for different stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have got some suggestion to use `pre_get_post` , I am giving you a snippet that will guide you to achieve your goal .You need to change the value passed for `terms` .

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_pre_get_posts_query' );

function custom_pre_get_posts_query( $q ) {

    if ( ! $q->is_main_query() ) return;
    if ( ! $q->is_post_type_archive() ) return;

    if ( ! is_admin() && is_shop() ) {

        $q->set( 'post__in', array( 99, 96, 93, 90, 87,83 ) );
        $q->set( 'cat', 'shoes' );

        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, it doesn't works. :-( I've added terms ids but it redirects me to 404 page.

Comment: I need to show all shoes with size 52, 53 and 54 if url contains "myfilter=typeA". So, I've set "'terms' => array( '52', '53, '54' )" if $_REQUEST['myfilter']=='typeA', but it doesn't works.

Comment: Check I have modified the function and let me know , if you are still having some problem.

Comment: It seems to work as expected. :D thank you bro. I'll let you know if I'll encounter problems.

Comment: I will be available for you . do not worry, I glad that It helped you.